GCP Load Balancer Health Check fails despite successful message in log
My GCP Load Balancer Health Check fails despite the logs showing me health check was ALLOWED.
created firewall rule - allow-health-check and made it as broad as possible. target - apply to all, filters - all ip ranges, protocols/ports - all, action - allow, priority - 1, network - default, logs - on
I added the tag "allow-health-check" to the instance template
I configured a Classic Application Load Balancer that uses that template/group
I can see the hit count increasing on the firewall policies page
The Load Balancing page says my load balancer's backend service is unhealthy even though
the logs show the following (I've redacted some info...):
{
  "insertId": ...
  "jsonPayload": {
    "rule_details": {
      "ip_port_info": [
        {
          "ip_protocol": "ALL"
        }
      ],
      "direction": "INGRESS",
      "action": "ALLOW",
      "source_range": [
        "0.0.0.0/0",
        "130.211.0.0/22",
        "35.191.0.0/16"
      ],
      "priority": 1,
      "reference": "network:default/firewall:allow-health-check"
    },
    "vpc": {
      "vpc_name": "default",
      "subnetwork_name": "default",
      "project_id": ...
    "disposition": "ALLOWED",
    "instance": {
      "region": ...
      "zone": ...
      "vm_name": ...,
      "project_id": ...
    },
    "connection": {
      "dest_ip": ...,
      "protocol": 6,
      "src_ip": "35.191.234.5",
      "src_port": 60520,
      "dest_port": 80
    }
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "gce_subnetwork",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": ...,
      "subnetwork_id": ...,
      "location": ...,
      "subnetwork_name": "default"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2024-09-24T02:48:53.776197575Z",
  "logName": "...,
  "receiveTimestamp": "2024-09-24T02:48:58.138012444Z"
}

